# Replace the username by the first name in WooCommerce email notifications

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, email-notifications

How do I show a user's first name in the WooCommerce emails instead of their username?

I just want to replace the username with the first name of the user. I want to add a small line before the email content and that line or phrase is "Hello **`[user's first name]`**,".

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to show thefirstname using the following shortcode:

```
{customer_first_name}
```

See the WooCommerce page for [email variables](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/automated-follow-up-emails-docs/email-variables-and-merge-tags/).

Comment: Is this possible to copy woocommerce email templates in a custom plugin and edit it. By default, the email starts from Hi {username} which I want to change to Hi {first_name} by copy into custom plugin

Comment: @HannahJames it shoul do as long as the emails are still processed via WooCommerce